# Gradle : how can I call a 'def' from an imported script?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am currently modularizing our gradle build in order to have a libs/commons.gradle file containing a lot of global stuff. I need this because of various branches of the software beeing developed in parallel and we'd like to avoid to spread every scriptfile change among all branches.

So I created that lib file and used "apply from" to load it :

apply from: 'gradle/glib/commons.gradle'

Inside commons.gradle I define the svnrevision function :

...

```
def svnRevision = {
    ISVNOptions options = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultOptions(true);
    SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance(options);
    SVNStatusClient statusClient = clientManager.getStatusClient();
    SVNStatus status = statusClient.doStatus(projectDir, false);
    SVNRevision revision = status.getCommittedRevision();
    return revision.getNumber().toString();
}
```

...

I am calling the function from my including build.gradle:

...

```
task writeVersionProperties {
    File f = new File(project.webAppDirName+'/WEB-INF/version.properties');
    if (f.exists()) { f.delete(); }

    f = new File(project.webAppDirName+'/WEB-INF/version.properties');
    FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
    os.write(("version="+svnRevision()).getBytes());
    os.flush();
    os.close();
}
```

...

But I end up in :

...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * Where:
    Build $PATH_TO/build20.gradle

    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'DEV_7.X.X_GRADLEZATION'.
    > Could not find method svnRevision() for arguments [] on root project 'DEV_7.X.X_GRADLEZATION'.
```

...

**So my queston is** : How can I call a subfunction in gradle, which is defined in an included script?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html:

> 13.4.1. Local variables
>
> Local variables are declared with the def keyword. They are only
>   visible in the scope where they have been declared. Local variables
>   are a feature of the underlying Groovy language.
>
> 13.4.2. Extra properties
>
> All enhanced objects in Gradle's domain model can hold extra
>   user-defined properties. This includes, but is not limited to,
>   projects, tasks, and source sets. Extra properties can be added, read
>   and set via the owning object's ext property. Alternatively, an ext
>   block can be used to add multiple properties at once.

If you declare it as:

```
ext.svnRevision = {
...
}
```

and don't change the call, I expect it will work.